# Why isn't there any captcha asked when running a new query in SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer, captcha

When I tried to create a new query on https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new, I didn't see any hint for me to work on CAPTCHA, so I just clicked Run Query, and the next page was https://data.stackexchange.com/query/save/1 whose content is only:

```
{"captcha":true}
```

Is it because of me being under the [GFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall)?

What can I do to make it work?